# Not able to add space inside input tag?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Using Material Ui Data Grid for display, inside data grid has input type.

Not able to add space between letters and the backstroke & front stroke keys not working.

Have to use this syntax as its being used at many places

Example:  Code Sandbox

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-architecture-o28sqb?file=/demo.tsx:112-123)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onCellKeyDown={(cellParams, MuiEvent) => {
      if (['Space', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight'].includes(MuiEvent.code)) {
        MuiEvent.stopPropagation()
      }
    }}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input
  onKeyDown={(event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }}
  name={"Abra Ka Dabra"}
  placeholder={"Gilli Gilli shu"}
/>
```

it will solve ur problem.